# send a friend in modal bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, send, friend

Well, before asking here I have tried to find an answer for the issue I  work with. Maybe someone who knows will help to find solution. I'm using bootstrap framework and here I have a "send friend" button which shows a modal fill-in form.

here's link: `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNvOPB?editors=100`

If fill out the form and press submit, it should send the data to the recipient.
`

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$sub ="$name, look this ";
$mes = "<b><u>Hi, $name.</u></b><p>text</p>";

$verify = mail ($email,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/html; charset = utf-8");
```

?>`

Individually all works fine, but if join together, the data don't come?
Please, help with sending data and back to modal as a confirmation.

I tried to solve this by myself for several days, but now I give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Send</button>
```

to

```
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm" >Send</button>
```

plus if you want to get a confirmation . try submiting the form via ajax. and get success as json response basis on which u can show the message and close the modal.

Comment: thanks a lot, now works. I wonder if you may help with back to modal as a confirmation.?

Comment: you can send the content like this  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
      if(data == success)
    });
});

Comment: here is example just send the data using ajax. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp and then return something when the email goes.

Comment: great. well basically the above problem was because data-dismiss"modal" causes the modal to close so the other actions ddnt perform... :)